ggplot geom_errorbar is adding too many error bars?
For some reason, geom_errorbar is adding way too many bars when I am trying to show the standard deviation for each class.
My code:
gplot(df, aes(x=Urban.Intensity, y=ITD.Avg, fill=Phenology)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(Genus~Sex, ncol=2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ITD.Avg-ITD.SD, ymax=ITD.Avg+ITD.SD), width=0.2)

Sample dataset:
> dput(df)
structure(list(Genus = c("Xenoglossa", "Agapostemon", "Xenoglossa", 
"Agapostemon", "Ceratina", "Agapostemon", "Xenoglossa", "Bombus", 
"Bombus", "Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", "Ceratina", "Agapostemon", 
"Ceratina", "Xenoglossa", "Xenoglossa", "Bombus", "Agapostemon", 
"Ceratina", "Xenoglossa", "Bombus", "Ceratina", "Bombus", "Agapostemon", 
"Agapostemon", "Agapostemon", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Agapostemon", 
"Bombus", "Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Xenoglossa", "Bombus", "Bombus", 
"Xenoglossa", "Agapostemon", "Ceratina", "Xenoglossa", "Agapostemon", 
"Ceratina", "Ceratina", "Xenoglossa", "Ceratina", "Agapostemon", 
"Xenoglossa", "Ceratina", "Xenoglossa", "Bombus", "Bombus"), 
    Sex = c("F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
    "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
    "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
    "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", 
    "F", "M", "F", "F"), Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L
    ), levels = c("2021", "2022", "2023"), class = "factor"), 
    Urban.Intensity = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("HIGH", 
    "MEDIUM", "LOW"), class = "factor"), Phenology = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Early", "Late"), class = "factor"), 
    ITD.Avg = c(3.16962352941176, 2.09492307692308, 2.9216, 1.84450588235294, 
    1.45745, 1.84623214285714, 2.9631, 3.54566423076923, 3.502548, 
    1.788, 2.12528048780488, 1.188, 2.035, 1.31057142857143, 
    2.8749125, 3.23634705882353, 3.56006551181102, 2.10714705882353, 
    1.39479166666667, 3.1623, 3.79701, 1.133, 3.486, 2.211, 2.10482608695652, 
    2.14428260869565, 1.4935, 1.43101764705882, 1.8095, 3.59898, 
    1.29608333333333, 1.21654285714286, 3.0279648, 3.22538, 3.604146, 
    3.31396363636364, 1.82789655172414, 1.3068125, 2.98357672131148, 
    2.13972, 1.18517142857143, 1.47136363636364, 2.99298, 1.1845, 
    2.07937078651685, 3.20292, 1.18328571428571, 2.985948, 3.34804054054054, 
    3.70393541899441), ITD.SD = c(0.270242054303986, 0.138843973476516, 
    0.222778644141925, 0.131155100542573, 0.13928142117926, 0.148439273297678, 
    0.346021415522219, 0.288453461454161, 0.407886647154307, 
    0.127653437086512, 0.149468711320987, 0, 0.0952627944162883, 
    0.0730841002837533, 0.330134432724326, 0.155989652371748, 
    0.30700923546087, 0.136212733812408, 0.178710689150556, 0.24649742392163, 
    0.219174817896582, 0.0852056336165632, 0.403810141031649, 
    0.132, 0.138951039234501, 0.119978951264085, 0.0897705943802569, 
    0.19280006518072, 0.154355730663895, 0.331725321975878, 0.107719978416262, 
    0.0805936899337836, 0.189695657897848, 0.269829025559673, 
    0.442247116844299, 0.150002421798631, 0.118166913332691, 
    0.0570969114021649, 0.232116862928435, 0.130506551559682, 
    0.106593644472908, 0.0716969075027267, 0.197044167637614, 
    NA, 0.119138515833697, NA, 0.113015106449157, 0.207744050600733, 
    0.447520878802417, 0.410989279187386), WW.Avg = c(2.04411764705882, 
    0.367132867132867, 1.74561403508772, 1.12549019607843, 1.26666666666667, 
    1.97321428571429, 1.85, 1.10576923076923, 2.18275862068965, 
    1.5, 0.536585365853659, 3.5, 0.333333333333333, 1.28571428571429, 
    1.95833333333333, 0.411764705882353, 1.26771653543307, 0.519607843137255, 
    1.5, 0.25, 2.8125, 0.333333333333333, 2.77777777777778, 1.5, 
    0.880434782608696, 0.807971014492754, 0.962962962962963, 
    1.63235294117647, 0.657407407407407, 1.95238095238095, 0.888888888888889, 
    3.5, 1.7, 1.76666666666667, 2.15, 1.22727272727273, 1.40229885057471, 
    0.25, 0.467213114754098, 0.92, 0.771428571428571, 2.81818181818182, 
    1.55, 0.5, 0.573033707865168, 4, 3.76190476190476, 0.3, 2.68918918918919, 
    2.41480446927374), WW.SD = c(1.23317554514095, 0.806991999871006, 
    0.940757706668748, 1.1921401283127, 1.22279928657082, 1.64984749393596, 
    1.02875329080073, 1.17713734876531, 1.45974092727183, 1.18321595661992, 
    0.958330878595497, 0.707106781186548, 0.577350269189626, 
    1.70433620649269, 0.988407989956541, 1.10729532699116, 1.40548143984198, 
    0.78639913979263, 0.774596669241483, 0.353553390593274, 1.32759180473518, 
    0.816496580927726, 0.905231707600018, 1.15470053837925, 1.01753942106925, 
    0.743149894420409, 0.919091586692722, 1.30447262959202, 0.866425000254559, 
    1.5644868320376, 0.820738150149675, 1.80277563773199, 1.64809472307153, 
    1.11210683353507, 1.42199403624141, 1.36681447833341, 1.29138262046557, 
    0.5, 0.956856191123725, 0.96479704256042, 1.08697405904742, 
    1.90095669693877, 1.01242283656583, NA, 0.796121856385381, 
    NA, 1.4108423691101, 0.4551294949164, 1.23227905214171, 1.44085208247252
    ), Abundance = c(34, 143, 57, 255, 15, 56, 10, 52, 290, 11, 
    82, 2, 3, 7, 48, 17, 127, 102, 6, 2, 16, 6, 9, 7, 46, 138, 
    27, 34, 108, 21, 9, 7, 75, 30, 180, 11, 87, 4, 61, 25, 35, 
    11, 10, 1, 89, 1, 21, 15, 74, 358)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L))

Why do some bars have so many error bars but others do not?


First, you have to add position = position_dodge(width = .9) to geom_errorbar too. Second, you have obs. for multiple years for some combos of Urban.Intensity, Phenology, Genus and Sex. For these cases an errorbar is added for each year (and of course are there multiple bars too which are plotted on top of each other).

To See this run e.g. df |> dplyr::add_count(Urban.Intensity, Phenology, Genus, Sex) |> dplyr::filter(n > 1) |> dplyr::arrange(Urban.Intensity, Phenology, Genus, Sex)
